# Why is ProGuard not obfuscating inner classes / enums

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, inner-classes, enumeration

I am trying to obfuscate some classes which contain a number of inner enums which I understand are compiled to separate standalone classes with the "$" separator by javac at compile time.

However, the problem I am having is that, although the contents of the enums are obfuscated, the parent / outer class as well as the enum class names themselves as well as their package names are not being obfuscated since the classes themselves are not being obfuscated.

We have specified ProGuard to keep various other classes within our proprietary packages (which are being dealt with correctly), but these should not be affecting the above mentioned classes.

Here is our `config.pro` file:

```
-injars .\build\libs\plugin.jar
-outjars .\build\libs\plugin_obfuscated.jar

-libraryjars .\jre\lib\rt.jar
-libraryjars .\jre\lib\jce.jar
-libraryjars .\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar

## Mapping
-classobfuscationdictionary .\config_classnames.pro
-packageobfuscationdictionary .\config_packagenames.pro

-printmapping .\build\libs\proguard_obfuscation_map.txt
-printseeds .\build\libs\proguard_seeds_map.txt
-printusage .\build\libs\proguard_deadusage_map.txt

## Shrinking
-dontshrink

## Optimizations
#-dontoptimize
-optimizations method/removal/parameter,method/inlining/short,
  method/inlining/unique
-optimizations code/removal/advanced,code/simplification/string,
  code/removal/exception,code/removal/variable,code/merging
-optimizations class/unboxing/enum
-allowaccessmodification
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
#-optimizationpasses 5

#-repackageclasses ''
-flattenpackagehierarchy 'software'

## Obfuscation
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-overloadaggressively

## Keep attributes
-keepattributes !InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,*Annotation*,Synthetic 
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml


# ProGuard doesn't print notes about classes with matching names
-dontnote com.google.**
-dontnote com.sun.**
-dontnote org.apache.log4j.**
-dontnote org.apache.logging.**
-dontnote com.itextpdf.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.io.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.commons.lang3.**
-dontnote org.hibernate.**

-dontnote **
-dontwarn **

# Keep specific proprietary classes
-keep class com.mycompany.product.framework.logging.** {
}

-keep class com.mycompany.product.plugin.persistence.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.mycompany.product.plugin.networking.** { 
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.mycompany.product.framework.automation.events.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.mycompany.product.plugin.events.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.mycompany.product.plugin.remote.** { 
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keepnames class com.mycompany.product.plugin.providers.* {
}

-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.product.framework.events.TestCase 
{
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep class members with @FXML annotations
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML
    <fields>;
    @javafx.fxml.FXML
    <methods>;
}

# Keep - Antlr library 
-keep class antlr.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep fasterxml
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { 
    <fields>;
    <methods>; 
}

# Keep - Google classes
-keep class com.google.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

... remaining other classes not to be included / sanitized
... followed by standard Proguard template configuration (truncated)

# Keep classes that implement Serializable
 -keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
 -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 
 'main' methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are 
 required in enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Keep - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

The classes we are trying to obfuscate, which include the inner / nested enum classes are under the package:

```
com.mycompany.packageContainingEnum1.enumOuterClass1
com.mycompany.packageContainingEnum1.enumOuterClass1$enum1ClassName
```

and

```
com.mycompany.packageContainingEnum2.enumouterClass2
com.mycompany.packageContainingEnum2.enumOuterClass2$enum2ClassName
```

As you can see, the packages which are giving the problems are below the "product" package and therefore should not be affected by the rules above?

Any ideas why the `enumouterClass2` and `enumOuterClass2$enum2ClassName` (enum) names are being preserved? This seems strange as by default, most people seem to have trouble preventing obfuscation of inner classes.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Ok, i think i have solved this - if I comment out `-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable` the enums are then obfuscated, since `Enum implements Serializable`.